# RxSwift parse JSON array

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, rx-swift

I'm trying to create an array of dictionaries from JSON response.

Here is the **code**.

```
_ = postView.textView.rx.text
        .subscribe(onNext: {[unowned self] _ in
            let client = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
            _ = client.request(Router.getFriends())
                .rx_responseJSON()
                .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] data in
                    var names = [String]()
                    do {
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any], //'var' declarations with multiple variables cannot have explicit getters/setters 
                            let friends = json["user"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                            for friend in friends {
                                if let name = friend["first_name"] as? String {
                                    names.append(name)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
                    }

                    print(names)
                    }, onError: { (error) -> Void in
                        debugPrint("Error: \(error)")
                })

        })
```

This is the **error** I'm getting

> 'var' declarations with multiple variables cannot have explicit
>   getters/setters

This is the **JSON response**,

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Knysys",
      "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large",
      "last_seen_event": null,
      "blocked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "ATester",
      "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/379988632393252/picture/?type=large",
      "last_seen_event": 7,
      "blocked": false
    }
  ]
}
```

The **desired output** is this,,

```
var friends = [
    [
        "firstName": "SmartApps",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/1248984075179327/picture/?type=large"
        ],

    [
        "firstName": "Knysys",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/437334666655912/picture/?type=large"
        ],
    [
        "firstName": "ATester",
        "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/379988632393252/picture/?type=large"
        ]
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: on which line you are getting this error?

Comment: On this one,

    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],

Comment: want to do small teamviewer session?

Comment: Thanks but I don't have Teamviewer rn. I've switched to some other project for now. But I'll need some solution that I can try when I work on this tomorrow.

Comment: i think the issue is that you need to remove the , from let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]

Comment: Ok. Will try it tmrw and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144308/discussion-between-shabir-jan-and-mjb).

Comment: I removed the line. But now I'm getting this error, **'let' declarations cannot be computed properties** in this line, `let friends = data["user"] as? [[String: Any]] {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked,

```
let client = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
_ = client.request(Router.getFriends())
    .rx_responseJSON()
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] data in
        self?.friends.removeAll()
        let json = data as? [String: Any]
        let friends = json?["user"] as! [[String: Any]]

        for i in 0 ..< friends.count{
            let firstName: String = (friends[i]["first_name"] as! NSString) as String
            let photo: String = (friends[i]["photo"] as! NSString) as String
            let dict = [
                "firstName" : firstName,
                "photo" : photo
            ]
            self?.friends.append(dict)
        }
        self?.friendTableView.reloadData()
        self?.friendTableView.sizeToFit()
        }, onError: { (error) -> Void in
           debugPrint("Error retrieving friends: \(error)")
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `if` in the line `let json = ...`

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
    let friends = json["user"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        for friend in friends {
            if let name = friend["first_name"] as? String {
                names.append(name)
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Adding if displays the following error,

**Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type 'with: (Any))'**

Comment: `data` should be of `Data` type. Can you confirm it? It seems your `data` parameter is `Any`